# html5 video embedding via M4V

Tags: html5-video, mp4, m4v

So I created a video using ScreenFlow on a Mac. Then exported it. It created an m4v file.  Then I changed the extension to mp4 and tried it out in the following web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=620">
<title>Fooo</title>

<script src="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.5/html5media.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video src="Demo.mp4" width="320" height="200" controls preload></video>


</body>
</html>
```

It does not play. If I move the pointer where the player is it will show the frame at where the pointer is. So all the frames are there but it will just not play the video.  What did I do wrong? How do I fix it?

Following @heff's advice, I deleted the script line. Once it was deleted I get this error message: "Video format or MIME type is not supported."

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that m4v == mp4? I think they're two different formats. You may be fooling the browser's movie player

Comment: @H2CO3, "However, unprotected M4V files without AC3 audio may be recognized and played by other video players by changing the file extension from ".m4v" to ".mp4". " source:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4v

How would i otherwise do it?

Comment: so that's not the problem, OK.

Comment: Could this be a browser problem?

Answer (score 0):

.mp4 == .m4v Different extensions for the same container format. Though .mp4 technically is also equal to .m4a, but .m4v != .m4a. At least I'm pretty sure. :)

Sounds like an issue with your javascript library. Have you tried just using the video tag in a browser that supports HTML5 video, with no library? Just delete the script line and see what happens.

Otherwise try posting a link to the live page where we can check it out.

Comment: Thanks! once the script was deleted I get this error message:
Video format or MIME type is not supported.  How would I go about doing this the right way if changing the extensions is not right?
Thanks!

Comment: My best guess then is ScreenFlow is using a codec that's not supported by browsers. Try running the file through another encoder like Handbrake or Miro, and see if the result of that works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved this, but you should go see the information on this webpage: [Video for Everyone!](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). Specifically, go see the first point of **section 2.1** where the author explains that your server must use the correct mime-types, and **section 3**, where the author explains what codecs you should use (because not every web-browser can read .m4v files).